# Get HTML from global variable (common) declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the HTML of the clicked anchor tag from global variable properties?

For example, I have Google, Yahoo, Apple etc. links and onClick of any link I need to alert this HTML.

I can achieve this by variable declaration inside function, but I have 3,000+ functions in same page with different class/id which I have difficulties to do so.

```
<a href="#" class="action g">Google</a><br>
<a href="#" class="action y">Yahoo</a><br>
<a href="#" class="action a">Apple</a><br>
<a href="#" class="action s">Samsung</a>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

```js
var myHtml = $(this).html();
$(document).on('click', '.action', function() {
  alert(myHtml);
});
```

I can do this by below code, but need to add the same code for all the functions

```
var myHtml;
$(document).on('click', '.action.g', function() {
  myHtml = $(this).html()
  alert(myHtml);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/6rmwnja1/)

Comment: Why not just use the common `.action` class to select them all, not specifically `.action.g`? Also having 3,000 functions in a single page sounds like a really big design flaw which needs addressing.

Comment: You can't use `this` at the top level / outside an event handler/callback.  You already have some code that provides a single event handler for all clicks and you (appear to have) exactly the same code for each of the 3000+ events - it's not clear why you're not combining the two methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works smoothly

```
$('.action').on('click', function(event){
  alert(event.target.text);
});
```

Her is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/nyutzb2s/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as suggested by @Rory

```
var myHtml;
$(document).on('click', '.action', function() {
  myHtml = $(this).html()
  alert(myHtml);
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use onclick on the links

```js
function a(e) {
  alert($(e).html())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="action g" onclick="a(this)">Google</a><br>
<a href="#" class="action y" onclick="a(this)">Yahoo</a><br>
<a href="#" class="action a" onclick="a(this)">Apple</a><br>
<a href="#" class="action s" onclick="a(this)">Samsung</a>
```